# App hangs up or "Not on FX application thread" occurs during app activity

Tags: java, javafx

The application reacts on actions which occur on gamepad. When button is pressed something happens on UI. But I ran at the issue with app hangs up or "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread" exception.

In order to fix it I tried the following approaches: `Platform.runLater()` and `Task` usage. But it didn't help.

Here is the problem code:

```
public class GamepadUI extends Application{

    private static final int WIDTH = 300;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 213;

    private Pane root = new Pane();
    private ImageView iv1 = new ImageView();

    private boolean isXPressed = false;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        initGUI(root);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.show();
    }

    public void pressBtn() {
        if(!isXPressed) {
            iv1.setVisible(true);
            isXPressed = true;
        }
    }

    public void releaseBtn() {
        if(isXPressed) {
            iv1.setVisible(false);
            isXPressed = false;
        }
    }

    private void initGUI(final Pane root) {
        Image image = new Image(Props.BUTTON);
        iv1.setImage(image);
        iv1.setLayoutX(198);
        iv1.setLayoutY(48);
        iv1.setVisible(false);
        root.getChildren().add(iv1);

        runTask();
    }

    public void runTask() {
        Task task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                initStubGamepad();
                return null;
            }
        };

        new Thread(task).start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void initStubGamepad() {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        try {
            while (true) {
                if (rnd.nextInt(30) == 3) {
                    pressBtn();
                } else if (rnd.nextInt(30) == 7) {
                    releaseBtn();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

`initStubGamepad()` emulates gamepad buttons activity polling. When user presses any button (`rnd.nextInt(30) == 3`) - an image appears on the UI. When user releases that button (`rnd.nextInt(30) == 7`) - an image disappears from the UI.

In case above `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread` occurs. If you change runTask() to something like this:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        initStubGamepad();
    }
});
```

Then app will hang or even main UI won't appear at all, but gamepad activity continues.

What I want is just to show/hide different images when some activity is detected on gamepad (btw, there's no way to monitor gamepad activity except for gamepad polling in an infinite loop). What did I wrong

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Explanation**

In the ***first scenario***, when you are using

```
Task task = new Task<Void>() {
  @Override
  protected Void call() throws Exception {
      initStubGamepad();
      return null;
  }
}
```

Inside `initStubGamepad()`, which is running on a **Task**, you are trying to update the UI components inside `pressBtn()` and `releaseBtn()` methods, which is why you are facing a

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread
```

because *all the UI updates must occur on the JavaFX thread*

In the ***second scenario***, when you are using

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        initStubGamepad();
    }
});
```

the UI doesnt appear, because you have an **infinite loop** inside the `initStubGamepad()`, which puts the JavaFX application thread run on an infinite loop

**Solution**

By the time you have reach here, you must have already found the solution. In case you haven't, try try to put the update the Javafx components on the UI thread. So, instead of calling `initStubGamepad()` inside `Platform.runLater`, try calling `pressBtn()` and `releaseBtn()` inside it.

Try using

```
while (true) {
   if (rnd.nextInt(30) == 3) {
      Platform.runLater(() -> pressBtn());            
   } else if (rnd.nextInt(30) == 7) {
       Platform.runLater(() -> releaseBtn());            
   }
}
```

or you may also use

```
public void pressBtn() {
    if(!isXPressed) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> iv1.setVisible(true));
        isXPressed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you very much for explanation. I understood what was wrong in my usage of `Platform.runLater()` and `Task` usage.